# xUnit.net Runners doesn't work on Visual Studio Online build server

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops, xunit.net

I am trying to get the xUnit 2.0.0-rc3-build1043 to work on VSO build agent, but are not able to get it to work. It doesn't fail, but returns with the message

> No test found. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors,
>   platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I have added the nuget packages for both xUnit.net and xUnit.net [Visual Studio Runner] with dependent packages, but somehow it seems that the runners isn't detected by the VSO build agent.

I have also tried to follow the steps described here in the post [Using XUnit with Visual Studio Online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214294/using-xunit-with-visual-studio-online) (modified for xUnit 2.x), but it doesn't work either, so I am a bit stuck.

I have tested both MSTest and nUnit and both of them works, so the build definition and the agent is working as they should.

So, does anyone know how to configure this to work?

Comment: Are you using the XAML based build system or the new Team Build?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I followed the documentation on the Visual Studio Online documentation: https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/build/run-tests-with-builds-vs

It worked for me :-)

Comment: I think I tried that, but I haven't checked this for a while now, so I have to retest it when I restart that project next week.

Comment: @MeMark, No, I gave up due to time pressure and haven't looked at it further afterwards